# [Chrome dev channel - Video issues]

Tags: google-chrome

I run:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86_64

Chrome Version 25.0.1323.1 dev

With the previous Crome's version (Chrome Version 24.0.1312.2 dev) I had general problems with videos, but I was able [to see the images and texts](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/737269/chrome_video_issues/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-05%2019:51:44.png) .

Today I updated to 25.0.1323.1 dev and now some videos have good sound [but no images](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/737269/chrome_video_issues/Screenshot%20from%202012-11-13%2013:22:11.png)  .

So far I found the worst issue in specific videos, if not maximized. Otherwise (if video is maximized/in fullscreen) the precedent behavior continue.

So:

- am I the only one with such issue?
- there is some Chrome version that does not have this problem (stable may be)?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to getting errors, you must use stable version not dev versions.

http://www.google.com/chrome

Comment: Thank you. Is it better to download the 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: According to your system's architecture,you must download 32 or 64-Bit version.
If your system is 32-Bit,You must download 32-Bit version. or 64-Bit download 64 Bit.
For learn it, look at `uname -a` output at the terminel.
If it say x86_**64**,your system is 64-Bit...

Comment: Of course, thank you. Actually I am back to Ubuntu after some years and I thought it was still preferable to choose a 32-Bit version of some applications.